# PHP same page echoing (using die funct.)

Tags: php

```
    <?php                    //filename signup.php
    ob_start();
 include('dat.php');
    if (!empty($_POST)){


        if ($pass!="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" OR $user!="") {       // 1
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_error()) {
                die('Sorry, this username already exists');                 // 2
            }
        } else {
        echo "Please enter the Password";
        }
    }

    ob_end_flush();
    ?>

<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="signup.php">                <!--3-->
Username<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" />
Password<input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword" />
e-mail<input name="email" type="text" id="email" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a sign up page (All the mysql details are missing here, they are included in dat.php) . If there is ny error , it is displayed in the same page.
problem 1 : [ //1 ] what is the operator for OR , in this case I have used the condition for if the pass or user is blank,but the OR is not working neither || , used in javascript.
problem 2 : [ //2 ] if die is used , then the statement is printed in the new window , but I want it to appear in the same window...I also used echo, it worked but I feel like i am missing the main function of 'die' by using 'echo'.
problem 3 : [ `<!--3-->` ] how can I replace signup.php as action to something like SERVER_PAGE or whatever...

Comment: @Svisstack do you want the actual code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [`OR`](http://php.net/language.operators.logical) is the same as `||` except that `OR` has a lower [precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) than `||`. This can cause logical errors when it’s used with other operators with a higher precedence than `OR` but a lower precedence than `||` like the assignment operators:

   ```
   $var = false OR true;  // ($var = false) OR true;
   var_dump($var);        // bool(false)
   $var = false || true;  // $var = (false || true);
   var_dump($var);        // bool(true)
   ```

   So I recommend you to rather use `||` than `OR`.
2. [`die`](http://php.net/die) does print the passed string and quits the execution of the current script. Personally, I wouldn’t use use `die` but implement a more decent error handling like storing the error message in a variable and print it in the document like this:

   ```
   $errors = array();
   if (!empty($_POST)) {
       if ($pass!="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" || $user!="") {
           $result=mysql_query($sql);
           if (mysql_error()) {
               $errors[] = 'Sorry, this username already exists';
           }
       } else {
           $errors[] = "Please enter the Password";
       }
   }
   if (!empty($errors)) {
       echo 'There were some errors:';
       echo '<ul><li>', implode('</li><li>', $errors), '</li></ul>';
   }
   ```
3. If you use an empty URL for the `action` attribute, it refers to the very same URL:

   ```
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
   ```

Some further tips:

- Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` to test the request method instead of testing `!empty($_POST)`.
- Avoid [register globals](http://php.net/security.globals). So use `$_POST['pass']` instead of `$pass` if you want to refer to the parameter *pass* passed by POST.

Comment: +1 nice form, I like the use of implode for error handling--also had no idea that a blank action posts to self

Comment: @Mikey1980: That’s a feature of URLs in general. So `<a href="">` does also refer to the very same document.

Comment: third one as i wanted `<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">`
  @Mikey : thanks

Comment: no worries, glad to find a question on Stack I can actually answer =P

Comment: still the first part is bugging me...when it was tested , it seems the operator not functioning, although the $pass is fine but when tried on $user, it did not work...`if ($pass!="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" || $user!="") {`

Comment: @tunetosuraj: That’s not quite the same: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` contains the URL path to currently executed script that can be different to the current requested URL path. Furthermore, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` must be treated as not trustworthy. So make sure to apply proper encoding on it like `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>"`.

Comment: @ltunetosuraj: This is probably an error in reasoning: The mentioned condition is met if either `$pass` does *not* have the value `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` or if `$user` is *not* empty. I guess you wanted this: `md5($pass)!="d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" || $user==""`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following form tag POST to the same script... that way if you rename the file it'll continue to work.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

problem 1: || (pipe pipe is OR)

problem 2: die stops dead right where it was called. Find a way to return false to the other script and die there.

problem 3: Not sure what you want here.

Comment: "or" is also "||". See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a [logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). The same as `||` but with [lower precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).
   What do you mean by *but the OR is not working neither ||* ? Do you get an exception? What should the result be? The syntax seems to be correct.
   Maybe you are using a wrong logical expression. What should it do? Currently it evaluates to `true`, if `$pass` is **not** `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` **or** if the `$user` is **not** empty.
2. Read about `die()` in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php), it is the same as `exit()`:

   > Output a message and terminate the current script

   It is perfectly valid to just use `echo` here, because you *want* that the script continues executing.
3. What do you mean? Something like:

   ```
   <?php  define('SERVER_PAGE', 'signup.php'); ?>
   // later
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo SERVER_PAGE ?>">
   ```

   ?

Answer (score 0):

first one and Second one:  As told by Gumbo

Answer for the third one:
3.`<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">`
@Mikey1980 : thanks!